# How can I call a function after an element has been created in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loaded

I want to call a function after an element has been created. Is there a way to do this?

Example:

```
$("#myElement").ready(function() {
    // call the function after the element has been loaded here
    console.log("I have been loaded!");
});
```

Comment: I don't know, I wrote it in the WYSIWYG editor. I wrote it to give people an example to what I am looking to accomplish.

Comment: When you mean created, do you mean appended to the DOM?

Comment: added a jsfiddle link to demo how to use `live`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666914/listening-to-events-such-as-adding-new-elements-in-javascript  posts a really nice solution to this problem.

Comment: Use [arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive) library.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

How are you creating the element?

If you're creating it in the static HTML then just use `.ready(handler)` or `.on("load", handler)`. If you're using AJAX though that's another kettle of fish.

If you're using jQuery's `load()` function then there's a callback you can run when the contents been loaded:

```
$('#element').load('sompage.html', function(){ /* callback */ });
```

If you're using jQuery's `$.ajax` or `$.get`/`$.post` functions then there's a success callback in that:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'somepage.html',
  success: function(){
    //callback
  }
});
```

If you're just creating the element and appending it like this:

```
$('body').append('<div></div>');
```

Then you can do this instead:

```
$('<div />', { id: 'mydiv' }).appendTo('body').ready(function(){ /* callback */ });
```

But this won't matter - because it's synchronous (which means that the next line of code won't run until it's added the element to the DOM anyway... - unless you're loading images and such) so you can just do:

```
$('<div />', { id: 'mydiv' }).appendTo('body');
$('#mydiv').css({backgroundColor:'red'});
```

But acctually, saying THAT you could just do this:

```
$('<div />', {id:'mydiv'}).appendTo('body').css({backgroundColor:'red'});
```

Comment: haha :) its the example you gave too! :p glad you got it working

Comment: Took me way too long to find this answer, but it works great and is easy to implement. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You may want to look into jQuery [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) events.  You attach an event handler to a selector that either matches now or after additional elements are created in your DOM.

So if you have a `<ul>` and you dynamically create new `<li>` items, in your `$(document).ready()` you can wire up a selector to an event handler so that all of your `<li>` elements will be wired for that event.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/hnMkS/) sample that demos `live`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand what's meant by it doesn't contain a split?  I'm sorry if I'm not understanding.

Comment: it was nice... I declare a lots of functions in normal syntax, is there any other way to change them to live?

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes this is needed for a DOM element created/loaded outside of your own script, either by a different js library or an event outside of your direct control.

For such scenarios, I always set an interval which checks periodically whether the target element exists and if this is true, the interval deletes itself and runs a callback function.

For this, I have a predefined function which I reuse:

```
function runAfterElementExists(jquery_selector,callback){
    var checker = window.setInterval(function() {
     //if one or more elements have been yielded by jquery
     //using this selector
     if ($(jquery_selector).length) {

        //stop checking for the existence of this element
        clearInterval(checker);

        //call the passed in function via the parameter above
        callback();
        }}, 200); //I usually check 5 times per second
}

//this is an example place in your code where you would like to
//start checking whether the target element exists
//I have used a class below, but you can use any jQuery selector
runAfterElementExists(".targetElementClass", function() {
    //any code here will run after the element is found to exist
    //and the interval has been deleted
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Creating an element does not mean much, unless it is inserted into the page. I think that is what you mean by `ready` function.

The `onLoad` event is limited to certain elements only, and is not supported for `div` or `p` elements. You have to options:

You can use `setInterval` function to check the existence of the element. Once the element is found, you can clear the interval:

```
var CONTROL_INTERVAL = setInterval(function(){
    // Check if element exist
    if($('#some-element').length > 0){
        // Since element is created, no need to check anymore
        clearInterval(CONTROL_INTERVAL);
    }
}, 100); // check for every 100ms
```

The second and the more idiomatic way is adding a mutation observer on the target element, and checking if the element is one of the elements inserted elements whenever target is mutated, i.e new element is added:

```js
let el = document.createElement("div");
el.innerHTML = "New Div";

const targetNode = document.querySelector("body");

const observerOptions = {
  childList: true,
  attributes: true,
  subtree: false
};

function callback(mutationList, observer) {
  mutationList.forEach((mutation) => {
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => {
      const isAdded = node.isEqualNode(el);
      console.log(isAdded);
    });
  });
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);

document.body.appendChild(el);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

There are two more alternatives, adding event listener for `DOMNodeInserted` or `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument` events but since `MutationEvent` is deprecated, it is best to avoid them.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent

Answer (score 1):

check out .live() its best after the element created,,

```
$('.clickme').live('click', function() {
      // Live handler called.
});
```

And then later add a new element:

```
$('body').append('<div class="clickme">Another target</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code

```js
$('body').on('click', '#btn', function() {
  $($('<div>').text('NewDive').appendTo("#old")).fadeOut(0).fadeIn(1000);
})
```

```css
#old > div{
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  font: 12px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" id="btn">Create Div</button>
      <div id="old">

      </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<div id=\"elem\"></div>").appendTo("#parent").each(function(){

   console.log("I have been created!");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

old thread, but in my case i had a situation with a big append-tree, and i wanted to do some initialization in-line so to speak, and did the following:

```
$("<div>").append(
  ...
  $("<div>").foo(...).bar(...).etc(...).each(function(){
    // init code to run after chain of init functions called
  })
...    
)
```

Answer (score -1):

The most straight-forward is to directly invoke the callback after creating the element :)