# Listening to events such as adding new elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, event-handling

I need to create an event listener such that, when a new element is added to the document, or any of its child, my event handler gets called.

Any ideas how to do this using?

Comment: @zeacuss: go here  http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
.bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved')
```

this are the events to check element is inserted or removed.

bind on parent element this event.

and call your function in handler

**js fiddle demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/PgAJT/

click here **for example**... http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php

Comment: it is now deprecated.. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Answer (score 28):

Mutation events are deprecated, use [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead. You can also use [arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/) library, it uses Mutation Observer internally and provides a nice simple api to listen for elements creation and removal.

```
document.querySelector('#container').arrive('.mySelector', function(newElem){
    // newElem is the newly injected element
});
```

Comment: Very nice library! Solved my current issue and will definitely be using it on future projects. Thanks, Uzair!

Comment: I could get this to work, but I added console.log snippets before and after the action (calling selectize on the selects) and I have a function that inserts 4 selects into a HTML table. Instead of triggering 4x, it kept triggering until code hang. Is there a way to prevent that? I used onlyOnce:true and it didn't crash out, but it only did it for the first select.

Answer (score 5):

DOMNodeInserted is deprecated in DOM Level 3 recommendation. using them slows browsers down (they say). depending on what you need it for, it might make sense to trigger a custom event inside the code where you insert the element.

Comment: actually, I'm not the one adding the nodes, so I can't handle it where it is added.