# how to scroll to bottom or move focus to bottom in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a div in which I added element .I want to scroll to bottom of the div whenever element added in div.I know how to do in in jquery .But I did not know how to scroll using angular js

testCaseContainer is id of div .

```
 var elem = document.getElementById('testCaseContainer'); // just to
                                                                    // scroll down
                                                                    // the line
        elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
```

I want to know how it is possible using angular ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/M8tCL8Szc3h3FatFLycG?p=preview

I added css in div container so that it scroll .

```
.heightClass{
  height:100px;
  overflow :auto;
}
```

how to move focus below when item is added ..please post your answer..

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution. It works for me .

**Template**

```
<div data-ng-controller="TestController">
    <button data-ng-click="AddNewItem()">Add New Item</button>
    <div class="heightClass" data-dr-scroll-to-bottom>
        <div data-ng-repeat="divItem in divList track by $index">
            {{divItem}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("TestController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    $scope.divList = [1, 2];

    $scope.AddNewItem = function () {
        $scope.divList.push(3);
    };

}]);
```

**Directive**
You have two options.

1. listen to DOMNodeInserted(This is deprecated. so don't you use it. learn more about it [Listening to events such as adding new elements in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666914/listening-to-events-such-as-adding-new-elements-in-javascript). For sake for convenience I have added the code . But don't use this code. Use Option 2).

   app.directive("drScrollToBottom", function() {

   var linkFunction = function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
       iElement.bind("DOMNodeInserted", function() {
         console.log(iElement.prop("scrollHeight"));
         iElement.scrollTop(iElement.prop("scrollHeight"));
       });
     };

   return {
       restrict: "A",
       link: linkFunction
     }
   });
2. ***use arrive.js***(can be found here https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/)

   app.directive("drScrollToBottom", function () {

   ```
   var linkFunction = function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
       iElement.arrive("div", function () {
           console.log(iElement.prop("scrollHeight"));
           iElement.scrollTop(iElement.prop("scrollHeight"));
       });
   };

   return {
       restrict: "A",
       link: linkFunction
   }
   ```

   });

Answer (score 0):

below is the directive to scroll to bottom of page

```
csapp.directive('csScrollTop', ["$window", function ($window) {
    var linkFunction = function (scope) {
        scope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function () {
            $window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
            //$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: linkFunction
    };
}]);
```

Comment: can you share plunker ..?I need to scroll that div which have contend..I don't need the scroll page ..I want to scroll the div (or move focus to bottom ) when item is added