# Attach scroll event handler to an dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, events, scroll

I'm using [simplescroll bar](https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar) (SSB), which adds wrappers around my scroll content on page load. And I need to attach an event listener, which would work on scroll.

Without SSB a simple

```
document.querySelector(".element").parentNode.addEventListener('scroll', handler);
```

did work. But now it doesn't work, since the right `.parentNode` doesn't exist yet, it will be added later on by SSB in background (I don't know when, I don't know how and I have no control on it).

**How do I attach scroll handler to dynamically created (not by me) element?**

With a click event I do use a function like this

```
function addPostponedEventListener(selector, eventName, handler)
{
    document.addEventListener(
        eventName, 
        e => 
        {
            const el = e.target;
        
            if (el.closest(selector))
            {
                handler();
            }
        }
    )
}
addPostponedEventListener('.element', 'scroll', handler);
```

but it works only with bubbling, and bubbling seems to be disabled for scroll event, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56128698/747050) I was able to do it:

```
function addPostponedEventListener(selector, eventName, handler)
{
    let interval = setInterval(() => 
    {
        let el = document.querySelector(selector);
        if (el)
        {
            el.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: MutationObserver sounds great! could you make an answer with it? There is no dependency on jQuery, $ was just a custom 1-line function, i've removed it from my answer, thanks.

Comment: @Ouroborus, I don't, I just add ss-container attribute to my scroll panel. It auto innitializes itself.